# .NET MVC 5 Only one area not working under IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have problem with one area in my project called 'Reports'. I always get 404 error when I try to access some controller from this Area. This problem only occurs when I run my application on local IIS (Windows 8.1). On other machine (windows 7 and local IIS) everything is ok. Even on this windows 8.1 machine, but IIS Express everything is working well.

I was trying to clear temp files, but no resuls.

Areas are registed such like this:

```
public class ReportsAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
{
    public override string AreaName 
    {
        get 
        {
            return "Reports";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Reports_default",
            "Reports/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

And in Global.asax, Application_start() method:

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
```

I dont know where could be the problem. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check event viewer. I had this problem and the 'Reports' URL was a virtual directory having to do with SQL Server Reporting Services.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class ReportsAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
{
    public override string AreaName 
    {
        get 
        {
            return "Reports";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Reports_main",
            "Reports/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { area = "Reports", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        context.MapRoute(
            "Reports_default",
            "Reports/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

The `Reports_default` routing rule sets `Index` to be the default action for a given controller.

You need to add another `Reports_main` rule that will set a default controller when you access the root of the area e.g. `/Reports`. In this rule I assume that the default controller is `Home` but you can change that to fit your project.

Answer (score 1):

The default `AreaRegistration` scaffold by Visual Studio does not include a default for `controller`, meaning that providing a controller in the URL is required.

```
/Reports/Home // This works (if you have a home controller)

/Reports // This doesn't work
```

To make the controller optional, you need to provide a default.

```
public class ReportsAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
{
    public override string AreaName 
    {
        get 
        {
            return "Reports";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Reports_default",
            "Reports/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            // Note that controller is defaulted to Home
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Note also that the order in which routes are registered is the same that they will be executed for the entire application. Typically, this means that you must call `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()` before you call `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)`.

The answer provided by Tasos will also work, but is incorrectly configured:

1. Specifying a default area within an `AreaRegistration` is redundant and unnecessary.
2. `Reports_default` in his example is an unreachable execution path, which makes it also redundant and unnecessary.

Comment: I tried this and this didnt work. I think that problem is somewere else. Few minutes ago I run this application on windows 7 local IIS, and everything is Ok. So I think that the problem is in configuration of local IIS on my computer.